# How to create a tiled gif (repeating the same small gif image in a tiled background)

Tags: wallpaper, gimp, gif

I have a gif image with a rather low resolution (500x200 pixels) which I would like to use to tile a wallpaper background (size 1920x1080 etc.) showing the same frame (or a different frame) on all copies.

The output should look like using gifview and enlarging the view area.

Is there a script to do this? (I know that I could split the gif in frames, then copy each frame to tile the bigger canvas and finally combine all back to a gif animation, but hopefully there is an automatic way to achieve this.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't GIMP an ["application packaged in *nix distributions"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), though?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the gifview display?

Answer (score 1):

**A hello world in ImageMagick can be:**

```
montage image.png image.png -geometry 200x500+10+10 -tile 2x1 tile_01.gif
```

Where **image.png** is your image and **tile_01.gif** is the path and file name that will be created. And then you can see the image tile_01.gif that has been created, a tiled image of 2x1 with your image, changing **-tile 2x1** with your preferences you can make your wallpaper.

[image: tiled image]

ImageMagick is extremely potent and have multiple choices. Probably you have it already installed, but if you haven't installed yet you can do it depending on your os, maybe:

Debian and derivates:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

YUM:

```
yum install ImageMagick
```

Usefull info:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick)

[ImageMagick manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/)